# C++ sscanf implementation issue (reading from a file)

Tags: c++, function

The problem is that with using sscanf. Expected result would be in for example case -> input from file (one line) 10 S teat xyz 11 12 -> all integers gets readed in seperate variables and S, teat, xyz all in seperate char variables.
In my case all integers readed correctly. Everything in between broken.

**Check test example in code below.**

In this case i must use chars, no strings available for this task.

How I can make that sscanf read the 3 words seperated by (n) spaces.

the right format is number, str, str, str, number, number (always like that from  file)

*I guess you understand problem now, as this is really easy, but had pause from C++, so yea. asking.*

```
bool addPerson(char *info) {
        char a;
        char b;
        char c;
        int ID;
        int motherID;
        int fatherID;

    // example STR:
    // 10 S teat xyz 11 12

    // RESULT
    // 10 z y x 11 12 -> so numbers got correctly

   sscanf(info, "%d%s%s%s%d%d", &ID, &a, &b, &c, &motherID, &fatherID);

   cout << ID << " ";
   cout << a << " "; 
   cout << b << " ";
   cout << c << " ";
   cout << motherID << " ";
   cout << fatherID;
   cout << endl;


   return 0;
   person *p = new person;
    if (first == NULL) first = last = current;
    else
        last = last -> next = p;
    current = p;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `%s` extracts a null-terminated string. The corresponding parameter points to a single, very lonely, `char`. This is not going to end well.

Comment: `%s` and address of a _single `char`_ won't work well. If you're seriously about learning c++ read about `std::string` and it's (easy and smooth) interworkings with `std::istream`. Drop `sscanf()` and start to use `std::istringstream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
char a;
sscanf(info, "%s", &a);
```

is syntactically correct but semantically incorrect.

When you use `%s` as the format specifier, you need to provide the location where a null terminated string can be stored. `&a` does not provide such a location.

You need something along the lines of:

```
char s[20 + 1]; // Make it large enough for your needs. 1 byte for null character ( '\0' )
sscanf(info, "%20s", s);  // Make sure to provide a number with %s
                          // so you don't read any more than what
                          // s can hold.
```

I'll leave you to fix your program appropriately using the above explanation.